# How do I remove the pause in my slideshow?

Tags: jquery, css

http://kennenmen.netai.net/home.php

I've been playing around with this for a few hours and its almost done. The only thing that's giving me trouble is I can't seem to work out why my slideshow has a pause after it cycles through all the images. Anyone got any idea as to why it's doing it?

```
function slideSwitch() {
 var $active = $('#slideshow img.active');
if ($active.is(':last')) {
    $active.hide().removeClass('active');
    $('#slideshow img:first').show().addClass('active');
}else{
    $active.hide().removeClass('active').next().show().addClass('active');
}
}

$(function () {
$('#slideshow img').not('.active').hide()
setInterval(slideSwitch, 1000);
});
```

Comment: What has PHP to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but you can try to use, instead of `setInterval`, the `setTimeout` in this way:

```
$(function () {
    $('#slideshow img').not('.active').hide()
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 8000);    // this depends on how many images there are 
});
```